# Bigrams and trigrams

Tags: python, topic-modeling

I am currently trying to create bigrams and trigrams to re-make my corpus from words only to both words and phrases, using [this Notebook](https://github.com/skipgram/modern-nlp-in-python/blob/master/executable/Modern_NLP_in_Python.ipynb) as my reference. However, phrases which I believe should yield from the code are not being compiled.

Here is the code I am using:

```
unigram_sentences = LineSentence("*.csv")                        

for unigram_sentence in it.islice(unigram_sentences, 1, 5):
print (u' '.join(unigram_sentence))
print (u'')  

intermediate_directory = os.path.join('.../2015/TEMP') 
bigram_model_filepath = os.path.join(intermediate_directory,'bigram_model_all')               


%%time

bigram_model = Phrases(unigram_sentences)
bigram_model.save(bigram_model_filepath)

# load the finished model from disk  

bigram_model = Phrases.load(bigram_model_filepath) 
bigram_sentences_filepath = os.path.join(intermediate_directory,
                                     'bigram_sentences_all.txt')      
%%time                                                              

with codecs.open(bigram_sentences_filepath, 'w', encoding='utf_8') as f:

    for unigram_sentence in unigram_sentences:

        bigram_sentence = u' '.join(bigram_model[unigram_sentence])

        f.write(bigram_sentence + '\n')                 

bigram_sentences = LineSentence(bigram_sentences_filepath)           

for bigram_sentence in it.islice(bigram_sentences, 1, 5):
print (u' '.join(bigram_sentence))
print (u'')
```

Practically my Ins (unigram sentences) are:

- yes but the self harm anxiety depression falls in to mental health
- they better alert county mental health of a possible before they put
  salty on the air
- bbc news plasters for the mind the rise in mental
  health first aid
- fixed my weird mood this morning by playing with
  makeup hshtg_makeup hshtg_charlottetilbury hshtg_mentalhealth

While my outs (bigram sentences) are:

- yes but the self_harm anxiety depression falls in to mental health
- they better alert county mental health of a possible before they put salty on the air
- bbc_news plasters_for the mind the_rise in mental health first_aid
- fixed my weird mood this morning by playing with makeup hshtg_makeup hshtg_charlottetilbury hshtg_mentalhealthList item

**While the code does combine such phrases as bbc_news and the_rise, what I would really expect here is to see mental_health being grouped together.**

Question: what am I doing wrong? :/

Thank you for your help and apologies for a messy 1st-timer post!

Alina